# Does MySQL log successful or attempted queries?

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm trying to track down a hit-or-miss bug in a web application. Sometimes a request completes just fine; sometimes it hangs and never finishes.

I see that Apache now has several requests listed on the server-status page as "sending reply," and that doesn't change. I'm testing on localhost, so there shouldn't ever be more than one.

Out of curiosity, I set MySQL to log all queries and I'm `tail -f`ing the log file.

When things go OK, I see a pattern like this:

```
20 Connect root@localhost on dbname
20 Query (query #1)
20 Query (query #2)
(etc)
20 Quit
21 Connect (etc)
```

When it hangs, I see a pattern like this:

```
22 Connect root@localhost on dbname
22 Query (query #1)
//nothing happens, so I try the post again
23 Connect root@localhost on dbname
23 Query (query #1)
//nothing happens; try again
24 Connect (etc)
```

Here's my question: **is MySQL logging *attempted* queries, or *successful* queries?** In other words, if the last line I see is query #1, does that imply that query #1 or query #2 is hanging?

My guess is that the one I don't see is the problem, because the last one I see looks fine, but maybe the one I don't see is too screwed-up for MySQL to process. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Queries are logged as they are received, which is not necessarily the order in which they are executed. So, this means the second query never arrives.

Maybe toy arround with the slow query and/ or error logging (see chapter 5.2 of the manual) a bit to see if your first query get logged there. If not, it's likely processed normally, and the problem is within your app.